# OpenLayers 3: get EPSG code of defined vector

Tags: openlayers, coordinate-system, epsg

The following code adds a GeoJSON from a string to my map. As long as the coordinate system of the added layer and the one of the map coincide this works fine.

```
var s = '{"type": "FeatureCollection","crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832" } },"features": [{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 325134.97109328309, 5714100.2438514316 ], [ 320302.04656303732, 5674502.1403005226 ], [ 348718.640573813, 5696776.5130852694 ], [ 325134.97109328309, 5714100.2438514316 ] ] ] } },{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 384899.1629929886, 5738888.2198651014 ], [ 372349.77042167314, 5702754.5424972903 ], [ 414864.97598753124, 5688620.0863007689 ], [ 426419.69267009723, 5722656.3482434982 ], [ 384899.1629929886, 5738888.2198651014 ] ] ] } }]}';

var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(s);

var vsource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: features
});

var geojsonVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vsource
});

map.addLayer(geojsonVector);
```

However, users will be able to add their *own* GeoJSON into a text input, and on button-click the feature will be read and added to the map. So, the variable *s* will be defined after the user has clicked a button.

For this to work properly it is essential that I detect the entered dataset's coordinate system, so I can transform it, if need be.

How can I detect the coordinate system?

*source.getProjection()*, as described in the [docs](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.ImageVector.html#getProjection) always returns null.

I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766126/get-the-epsg-code-from-openlayers-3-layer), but it does not recognize *getCode()*:

```
layer.getSource().getProjection().getCode()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the readProjection method on the GeoJSON parser: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.GeoJSON.html#readProjection